# ServiceStack - Repository Injection By Name

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, servicestack

All,

I have read up on the way SS uses Func to wire registrations. My current issue is that I am still not seeing how to call a specific instance from runtime.

What I would like to do is set up two different repository classes representing two different database systems, say SQLDB and MongoDB, both of which inherit from IDB, then be able to determine which database to use based on an app setting in the config file.

What I have right now in my Configure method is just

```
container.Register("SQLDB", new TestSQLDB("connectionName"));
container.Register("MongoDB", new TestMongoDB("mongoURL"));
```

If anyone can help me fill in the blanks I'd appreciate it. I already managed this with Ninject, but I would prefer not to have to add it if I don't need to.

Thanks,
Bs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your help Gavin. You got me on the right track. Here is what worked.

1) In the config:

```
container.Register<ITest>("SQLDB", new TestSQLDB("xxxx"));
container.Register<ITest>("MongoDB", new TestMongoDB("mongo://127.0.0.1"));
```

2) In the service:

```
IAppHost appHost = base.GetAppHost();
var repository = appHost.GetContainer().ResolveNamed<ITest>("MongoDB");
List<Test> testlist = repository.LoadAll();
```

This way I can just replace "MongoDB" with something from the config file and I don't need to recompile to change data sources.

Answer (score 3):

Register via concrete type (or interface if you prefer):

```
container.Register<SQLDB>(new TestSQLDB("connectionName"));
container.Register<MongoDB>(new TestMongoDB("mongoURL"));
```

When you want one back:

```
var mySqlDB = container.Resolve<SQLDB>();
var myMongoDB = container.Resolve<MongoDB>();
```

Comment: Hi Gavin,

Thanks for the reply. This gets me a little bit closer. What I was hoping for was to be able to do something like get the name of the DB system I want to use from the config file, then pass that off in order to automatically select the correct type. I can do this in Ninject by adding a string name to the registration, then calling the instance by string when I need it. If I use the concrete type or interface above, I would need a switch on my config value.